# Building and installing a Teams bot app for on-premises softwares

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-appstudio

I am quite new to Teams and to building bots for it.
Using NodeJS, I built a simple prototype one that can receive notifications and send requests to my software.

However, my software is installed on-premises, which means all users using it have a different domain name for it (xxx.com, abc.com…). To be able to use it, the app needs to know what is the endpoint of the requests.

**I wonder how I can build my bot app in those conditions and have it in the Teams Marketplace.**

My question is :
I assume I want a team admin to set the domain name in some app settings before installing it for a team and users to use.
**Is that possible somehow? Is it even possible to build such an bot app?**

I suppose it is possible to achieve that by having the users install a custom app, but then the app cannot be in the Marketplace.
I also suppose I can ask individual users to first enter the name of the domain, it sounds repetitive and the info would then be stored in some `userData`.
**Isn't there some `teamData` instead?** Could it mean having one user set those information and have them stored for everyone?

Comment: could you please take a look at [Region Selection App sample code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-region-selection/csharp)?

Comment: are you still blocked on this?